# Why is commenting out multiline comments in c++ inconsistent?

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-construction, comments

So we know that

```
// This doesn't affect anything

/*
This doesn't affect anything either
*/

/*
/* /* /*
This doesn't affect anything
*/
This does because comments aren't recursive

/* /*
This doesn't affect anything
*/ */
This throws an error because the second * / is unmatched since comments aren't recursive
```

I've heard that the reason they aren't recursive is because they would [slow down the compiler](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81072/why-do-most-programming-languages-not-nest-block-comments), and I guess that makes sense. However nowadays when I'm parsing c++ code in a higher level language (say Python), I can simply use the regular expression

```
"\/[\/]+((?![\n])[\s\S])*\r*\n"
```

to match `// single line comments`, and use

```
"\/\*((?!\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/"
```

to match `/* multiline comments */`, then loop through all single line comments, remove them, then loop through all multi-line comments and remove them. Or vice versa. But that's where I'm stuck. It seems that doing one or the other isn't sufficient, because:

```
// /*
An error is thrown because the /* is ignored
*/

/*
This doesn't affect things because of mysterious reasons
// */
```

and

```
/*
This throws an error because the second * / is unmatched
// */ */
```

What is the reason for this behavior? Is it also an artifact of the way the compilers parse things?  To be clear I don't want to change the behavior of c++, I would just like to know the reasoning behind the second set of examples behaving they way they do.

Edit:

So yes, to be more explicit, my question is why the following three (seemingly reasonable) ways of explaining this behavior don't work:

1. Simply ignore all characters on a line after // regardless of whether they are /* or * /, even if you are in a multiline comment.
2. Allow a / * or */ followed by a // to still have effect.
3. Both of the above.

I understand why nested comments aren't allowed, because they would require a stack and arbitrarily high amounts of memory. But these three cases would not.

Edit again:

If anyone is interested, here is the following code to extract comments of a c/c++ file in python following the correct commenting rules discussed here:

```
import re
commentScanner = re.Scanner([
  (r"\/[\/]+((?![\n])[\s\S])*\r*(\n{1})?", lambda scanner, token: ("//", token)),
  (r"\/\*((?!\*\/)[\s\S])*\*\/", lambda scanner, token: ("/* ... */", token)),
  (r"[\s\S]", lambda scanner, token: None)
])
commentScanner.scan("fds a45fsa//kjl fds4325lkjfa/*jfds/\nk\lj\/*4532jlfds5342a  l/*a/*b/*c\n//fdsafa\n\r\n/*jfd//a*/fd// fs54fdsa3\r\r//\r/*\r\n2a\n\n\nois")
```

Comment: You have said "it wouldn't be _that_ slow" but didn't make a case for why the language should be changed to allow nested comments. If you can provide one, I can tell you why it's not as important as leaving things the way they are.

Comment: No I don't think the language should be changed. I am just wondering how to parse it and follow the behavior the compilers chose.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to roll custom C++ parsers. Use Clang if you have a serious need to parse C++.

Comment: Okay I agree but that's besides the point.

Comment: Okay now I'm confused. Are you asking why we don't have nested comments in C++, or how to parse C++ given that we don't? (Which is _easier_ than if we did...)

Comment: I'm wondering why the second set of examples have the behavior they exhibit. How // interacts with /* and */ strangely. Why is this?

Comment: What other behaviour would you like them to exhibit?

Comment: The biggest thing it that seems odd to me is that you can use // to comment out /*, but you can't use it to comment out */. Why?

Comment: It seems like it would make sense to be able to comment out both for consistency, but that's why I'm asking is because they chose a different behavior and I would like to understand why.

Comment: @DanielleEnsign the `//` can't comment out the `*/` because the `//` is commented out by the `/*`.

Comment: It's completely "consistent"... comments don't nest. In your final example, the first `*/` ends the comment, the second `*/` is erroneous, and the `//` is just part of the plaintext comment content because _comments don't nest_.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense, thanks. Okay cool. So /* and */ have precedence over //??

Comment: No, there's no "precedence". Comments don't nest. If `/*` is found, all subsequent characters until `*/` are a comment. If `//` is found (not including inside a comment, because _comments don't nest_), all subsequent characters until newline are a comment. Simple!

Comment: This question will make two million upvotes or downvotes and let them into oblivion.

Comment: Okay, I see. So essentially, the compiler runs along, and when it reaches a // it will ignore everything after that on that line (including /* or * /). Then as it continues on (on lines after this commented out one), if it runs into /*, it will ignore everything after that until it hits a * / (including // and more /*) Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielleEnsign: Yes. How else would it work? :)

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense =) Thanks =)

Comment: In retrospect that does seem like the most consistent behavior. One alternative is to simply ignore all characters on a line after // regardless of whether they are /* or * /, even if you are in a multiline comment. Or you could allow a / * followed by a // to still have effect.

Comment: Why does she get those down votes?
It's a fairly well formatted question, on topic, and she clearly spent effort and time both trying to work out the problem and writing it.

Comment: You're saying "one alternative would be to have nested comments". We know. :)

Comment: So the important part is neither of these require a stack (and potentially an arbitrarily high amount of memory) that nested comments (aka /* /* */ */ being valid) would.

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad: It's not too bad with the context of the comments, but the question itself doesn't do a good job of explaining what the actual problem is (instead expecting it to be obvious, which is difficult when there turns out not to be one!). And unfortunately just spending time on it is not enough.

Comment: @DanielleEnsign: It would also be more difficult for syntax highlighters, and for people. There's simply no reason to allow it. This is kind of like asking "why don't we add a square wheel to our cars?"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Weird, I got it immediately. But I can see it might be hard to get if you take a different train of thoughts.

Comment: `#if 0` / `#endif` will nest quite nicely.

Comment: @HenrikKjusAlstad: Good for you

Comment: @DanKorn: They're not comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *inconsistent.* The existing behaviour is both easy to specify and easy to implement, and your compiler is implementing it correctly. See [lex.comment] in the standard.

> The characters `/*` start a comment, which terminates with the characters `*/`. These comments do not
>   nest. The characters `//` start a comment, which terminates with the next new-line character. If there is a
>   form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such a comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it
>   and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required. *[ Note:* The comment characters
>   `//`, `/*`, and `*/` have no special meaning within a `//` comment and are treated just like other characters.
>   Similarly, the comment characters `//` and `/*` have no special meaning within a `/*` comment. — *end note ]*

As you can see, `//` can be used to comment out both `/*` and `*/`. It's just that comments don't nest, so if the `//` is already inside a `/*`, then the `//` has no effect at all.

Comment: So // can't be used to comment out * /, otherwise the 3rd to last example would cause a compiler error (which it doesn't). However it does comment it out if it doesn't have matching things, but point is it still blocks the /* from matching with a further */ like you would expect it to do (since */ shouldn't do anything when it's commented)

Comment: @DanielleEnsign `//` does comment out `*/` though. If you have `// */` at the beginning of a file, for example, you won't get an error. But as I say, `//` has no effect (it is not interpreted as a comment marker) if it occurs inside a comment itself.

Comment: @DanielleEnsign It can comment out `*/` except when `//` is already within `/*` (i.e., `//` is commented out and has no affect).

Comment: Okay cool, this quote takes a bit to wrap your head around because it doesn't provide examples to make explicit what it means, but it does fully describe the correct behavior so once one writes out the seeming edge cases they can apply this to them and understand the correct behavior. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah like everything inside a comment is just text, but when you remove the comment delimiter,
the exposed text becomes available to be parsed again.
So if part of that text had comment delimiter literals, they become parse-able as a new comment *delimiter*.

And its always a first come, first serve issue, i.e. left to right order.

It might be a little simplistic to think that parsing comments is simplistic.
The fact is that quotes must be parsed at the very same time (both single/double) and whatever is first encountered comments/quote, is served first.

Finally, everything inside a comment being skipped means that if you remove the outter
comment layer, everything remaining *not* a valid comment will be parsed as
part of the language. That means there is no certainty about any exposed comment format,
and the chances of getting a parse error is great, if not inevitable.

I believe also that C++ has a line continuation form for `//` style comments as well.
For example:

```
// single line continuation\
continuation               \  
end here 
code
```

So the formula to parse C++ comments with regular expressions is that you have
to parse (match) every single character in the file.
If you just go straight for the comments it *will* inject the match into
the wrong place.

A good regex to parse comments is below. I originally got this off a Perl group
and slightly modified it for single line comment and continuation.
With it you could remove comments or just find comments.

Raw regex:

```
   # (/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/|//(?:[^\\]|\\\n?)*?\n)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|[\S\s][^/"'\\]*)


   (                                # (1 start), Comments 
        /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
        [^*]* \*+
        (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
        /                                # End /* .. */ comment
     |  
        //                               # Start // comment
        (?: [^\\] | \\ \n? )*?           # Possible line-continuation
        \n                               # End // comment
   )                                # (1 end)
|  
   (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
        "
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
        "
     |  '
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
        ' 
     |  [\S\s]                           # Any other char
        [^/"'\\]*                        # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                         # or line continuation (escape + newline)
   )                                # (2 end)
```

Enhanced (preserve formatting), mostly used to *delete* comments.
Use multi-line mode:

```
   # ((?:(?:^[ \t]*)?(?:/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/(?:[ \t]*\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//)))?|//(?:[^\\]|\\(?:\r?\n)?)*?(?:\r?\n(?=[ \t]*(?:\r?\n|/\*|//))|(?=\r?\n))))+)|("(?:\\[\S\s]|[^"\\])*"|'(?:\\[\S\s]|[^'\\])*'|(?:\r?\n|[\S\s])[^/"'\\\s]*)

   (                                # (1 start), Comments 
        (?:
             (?: ^ [ \t]* )?                  # <- To preserve formatting
             (?:
                  /\*                              # Start /* .. */ comment
                  [^*]* \*+
                  (?: [^/*] [^*]* \*+ )*
                  /                                # End /* .. */ comment
                  (?:                              # <- To preserve formatting 
                       [ \t]* \r? \n                                      
                       (?=
                            [ \t]*                  
                            (?: \r? \n | /\* | // )
                       )
                  )?
               |  
                  //                               # Start // comment
                  (?:                              # Possible line-continuation
                       [^\\] 
                    |  \\ 
                       (?: \r? \n )?
                  )*?
                  (?:                              # End // comment
                       \r? \n                               
                       (?=                              # <- To preserve formatting
                            [ \t]*                          
                            (?: \r? \n | /\* | // )
                       )
                    |  (?= \r? \n )
                  )
             )
        )+                               # Grab multiple comment blocks if need be
   )                                # (1 end)

|                                 ## OR

   (                                # (2 start), Non - comments 
        "
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^"\\] )*        # Double quoted text
        "
     |  '
        (?: \\ [\S\s] | [^'\\] )*        # Single quoted text
        ' 
     |  (?: \r? \n | [\S\s] )            # Linebreak or Any other char
        [^/"'\\\s]*                      # Chars which doesn't start a comment, string, escape,
                                         # or line continuation (escape + newline)
   )                                # (2 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

When a comment starts, everything until the end of the comment is treated as a comment.

So `zero // one */ two` all by itself could have `zero // one */` be the end of a `/* */` comment from a previous line, two `two` outside the comment, or it could be a new single-line comment that starts `// one */ two`, with `zero` out side the comment.

As a theory why this was done, `//` is not a valid C token or token sequence.  So there are no programs with `//` outside of a comment or string in C.

However, `//` within a comment would be legal.  So a header file containing:

```
/* this is a C style comment
// with some cool
// slashes */
```

would break if we made `//` comment out the trailing `*/`.  Within a `/* */` comment, `//` is ignored.  Compatibility with C was not to be broken for no good reason.

And within a `//`, everything gets ignored until the end of the line.  No sneaky `/*` or allowed.

The parsing rule is really easy -- start a comment, slurp and discard until you see the end token (either a newline, or a `*/` depending), then continue parsing.

As C++ is not designed to be parsed by regular expressions, your difficulty parsing it with regular expressions was either not considered, or not considered important.